# nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/autoindex : "off" is not working in azure ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have my web application deployed, which is angular application. I wanted to restrict the user to see the /assests directory and the publicUrl directory listing, so tried by doing autoindex off. But it not worked. This is my annotations in ingress controller :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBRmA.png)

What could be the issue, and both the azure and nginx-ingress controller are deployed. So please suggest the solution.

Tried multiple things, but not worked.